# Calculate weighted percentiles using SQL

Tags: sql

How can I calculate weighted percentiles using a single SQL statement? Suppose I have the following table with 2 columns, data and weights:

**Sample Input:**

```
   (data, weights)
    (1, 0.25)
    (1.5, 0.55)
    (2, 0.65)
    (2.5, 0.34)
    (3, 0.15)
    (3.5, 0.10)
    (4, 0.05)
    (4.5, 0.75)
    (5, 0.40)
```

**Sample Output:**

```
(percentile, weightedPercentile)
(1,1)
(2,1)
(3,1)
(4,1)
.
.
.
(50,2.5)
(51,2.5)
.
.
.
(98,5)
(99,5)
```

How can I calculate and display all of the weighted percentiles (1 through 99) in a single SQL statement?

Note: the weights must be normalized to 1.

Comment: . . I removed the incompatible database tags.  Tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Please provide a sample output.

Comment: @BorisJovanovic sure thing. I created a sample output and added it to the question

Comment: Could you please explain how your input needs to be transformed. Maybe it's the language barrier but I don't seem to understand what needs to be done.

Comment: @Carnageta: you would need to provide a better explanation of what you are trying to do. Otherwise, you are not likely to get a proper answer, even with a bounty on the question. Please describe the logic to get the desired results.

Comment: I agree with Anastas and GMB, you've not described the process you're doing to reach the expected output. Will you add an explanation after the bounty? Seriously!

Answer (score 4):

The question is vague. Anyway let's give it a try.

Expected output: `(50,2.5)` -- median

It seems that median should be equal 3.0 and not 2.5 - please check if that is correct

---

The idea is to multiply the weight by 100 and replicate each result the number of times and then calculate percentile from 1 to 99.

```
WITH tally_table AS  (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s) AS c
   FROM
   (select 0 AS s union all select 1 union all select 2 union all 
    select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all 
    select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t
   CROSS JOIN
   (select 0 AS b union all select 1 union all select 2 union all
    select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all
    select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t2
), weight_as_int AS (
  SELECT data,CAST(weights * 100 AS INT) AS weights
  FROM t
), multipied_values AS (
  SELECT data, weights
  FROM weight_as_int t
  JOIN tally_table
    ON t.weights <= tally_table.c
)
SELECT DISTINCT 0.01 * 100 AS percentile,
       PERCENTILE_DISC(0.01) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY data)OVER () AS weightedPercentile
FROM multipied_values
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 0.02 * 100 AS percentile,
       PERCENTILE_DISC(0.02) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY data)OVER () AS weightedPercentile
FROM multipied_values
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 0.03 * 100 AS percentile,
       PERCENTILE_DISC(0.03) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY data)OVER () AS weightedPercentile
FROM multipied_values
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 0.04 * 100 AS percentile,
       PERCENTILE_DISC(0.04) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY data)OVER () AS weightedPercentile
FROM multipied_values
UNION ALL
-- here goes the rest of 5 to 48
SELECT DISTINCT 0.49 * 100 AS percentile,
       PERCENTILE_DISC(0.49) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY data)OVER () AS weightedPercentile
FROM multipied_values
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 0.50 * 100 AS percentile,
       PERCENTILE_DISC(0.50) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY data)OVER () AS weightedPercentile
FROM multipied_values
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 0.51 * 100 AS percentile,
       PERCENTILE_DISC(0.51) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY data)OVER () AS weightedPercentile
FROM multipied_values
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 0.98 * 100 AS percentile,
       PERCENTILE_DISC(0.98) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY data)OVER () AS weightedPercentile
FROM multipied_values
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 0.99 * 100 AS percentile,
       PERCENTILE_DISC(0.99) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY data)OVER () AS weightedPercentile
FROM multipied_values
ORDER BY percentile;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a40c7fe2041bc93d613a7e8b85a3f3cb)**